# How do I release self (UIImageView) in touchesEnded?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uiimageview, self

I have an object that is a child of UIImageView. Before all these touches methods, I add this object to the superview and then user moves it. In touchesEnded, sometimes I want to release self. I've tried:

```
- [self release]
```

or

```
- [self removeFromSuperview]
```

But all these tries end up in exceptions. What's the right way to release self?

Comment: You don't. When you add the super view, make sure it is autoreleased or release the reference just after you add it. When you do [self removeFromSuperview] the super view will release it for you.

Comment: That's what I did!

I just found where the problem was.
I moved [super dealloc] in dealloc method from the 1st line to the bottom of dealloc and it works now :) Thank you

Comment: Oh yeah, [super dealloc] always has to be the last thing in your dealloc method otherwise your object will be gone when the method returns :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot release self. self is main view and if you want to remove object from UIImageView then you have to remove it using that object name. `[objNameSubViewOFUIImageView removeFromSuperview]`